# How to compile tensorflow for avx instructions on windows machine using bazel and msys2?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to compile tensorflow for avx instructions on a windows 10 machine. I have downloaded the tensorflow-master repository, bazel and msys2. I tried to compile it using the command
`bazel --batch build -c opt --copt=-mavx  -k //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`
but could not compile it. Can anyone prove me a step by step guide or an alternative solution?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using GCC/MSYS or Visual Studio as the C++ compiler? For Visual Studio, use `--copt=/arch:AVX`.

Comment: I was using VS14. I will give it a try. Thanks!